# How do I aggregate feeds together in a string and then parse them?

Tags: python, xml, concatenation, feed

I am trying to aggregate a few youtube feeds, concatenate them, and then parse the feeds.
When I parse the individual feed on their own, I have no trouble and the code seems to work.  However, when I try to aggregate the feeds as one long string and then use etree.fromstring(aggregate_partner_feed), I get an error.  The error I get is ParseError: unbound prefix and the etree line (referenced earlier) is given as the error.  Any advice on how to fix this?

```
aggregated_partners_list = [cnn, teamcoco, buzzfeed]


i = 1 
number_of_partners = len(aggregated_partners_list)
aggregate_partner_feed = '' 

for entry in aggregated_partners_list:
    #YOUTUBE FEED
    #download the file:
    file = urllib2.urlopen('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/'+entry+'/uploads?v=2&max-results=50')
    #convert to string:
    data = file.read()
    #close file because we dont need it anymore:
    file.close()

    if i == 1:
        #remove ending </feed>
        data = data[:-7]

    if i>1 and i != number_of_partners:
        data = data[data.find('<entry'):]
        data = data[:-7]
        #remove everything before first <entry> in the new feed and the last </entry>

    #if last, then only remove everything before first <entry>
    if i == number_of_partners:
        data = data[data.find('<entry'):]

    #append the current feed to the existing feed
    aggregate_partner_feed += data

    #increment the counter  
    i=i+1

print isinstance(data, basestring)                      #returns true
print isinstance(aggregate_partner_feed, basestring)    #returns true

#apply the parsing to the aggregated feed

#entire feed
root = etree.fromstring(aggregate_partner_feed)     #this is the line that give an error
#all entries
entries = root.findall('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry')
#more code that seems to work...
```

Comment: Could you show the value of `aggregate_partner_feed`?

Comment: you could parse each feed individually using etree and append parsed entries to a combined tree object instead of manually manipulating xml as a string

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian how do I append the parsed entries to a combined tree object?

Comment: Using the [Youtube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/1.0/developers_guide_python) instead of parsing the raw feeds may help to simplify your code.

Comment: @sharataka: each element is a collection of its children e.g., there is `.append()` method

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian if you write as an answer, I can give you credit :)

Comment: It is encouraged to answer your own questions. If .append() fails; update your answer with specific errors that you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I parsed each feed individually and then used .append instead of concatenating the strings together and then parsing.